# Characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f(x)= x^2$ ; $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\chi$ is the characteristic function of $[0,9]$, of what subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the composition $\chi \circ f$ is a characteristic function?

My answer:-
The composition gives me $\chi (x^2) = 1$ when $x$ is in $[0,9]$, and $\chi(x^2)= 0$ when $x$ is not in $[0,9]$.
So, can I say $\chi$ is a characteristic function of  $[0,9]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation are not right, you got that $\chi\circ f (x)=1$ iff $x\in[-3,3]$ since $x^2\in[0,9]$. Otherwise $\chi\circ f (x)=0$ then $\chi\circ f =\chi_{[-3,3]}$ i.e the characteristic function of $[-3,3]$.